# data-autoplay not always working in jQueryfullPage.js

Tags: javascript, html, fullpage.js

i'm developing an html page using jQueryfullPage.js, inside this page i integrated like 17 videos in 17 different sections, these are youtube iframes with data-autoplay attribute. Everything is working fine, the videos are only playing when we are on(viewport) the section containing the video, except that there are specific sections that the videos are auto playing on page load even when we aren't on the section containing this video. there are 3/17 videos that are playing automatically, but the rest of them are working properly. Any help? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

From [the fullPage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#auto-playpause-embedded-media):

> Using the attribute autoplay for videos or audio, or the param autoplay=1 for youtube iframes will result in the media element playing on page load. In order to play it on section/slide load use instead the attribute data-autoplay.

Make sure they don't contain `autoplay=1` in the video URL.

Comment: Yes that's what i did all the attributes are data-autoplay, i didn't use any autoplay=1 attribut, i even changed the iframe position to another section, i noticed that the same sections are making this problem, could it be a problem in the section? There is no javascript error at all

Comment: We'll never know until you provide a reproduction I'm afraid.